# Extreme performance degradation with JQuery and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, internet-explorer

I used the following query to select 2 elements by content:

```
$('.a .b:contains("Padding Before"), .a .b:contains("Padding After")');
```

This query was extremely slow and takes 2 seconds on my pc to execute. Without `:contains` it will return a data set with only 11 elements.

Then I tried to optimize it:

```
$('.a .b:contains("Padding")'); // or similiar query, but the result set is the same - 2 elements
```

I used internet explorer 10 for tests and I expected that after modification it will be executed 2 times faster.

Instead of this, now it executed dozens or hundred times faster.

So, how is it possible, that query concatenation have a such extreme impact on query performance?

I can just make the same query 50-100 times faster if I do the same but with 2 queries:

```
var n = $('.a .b:contains("Padding After")')
var m = $('.a .b:contains("Padding Before")');
```

Is this a bug in JQuery 1.8.23 / IE or what is the reason for this performance degradation? On Chrome there is no such problems.

Comment: as far as I know it is not a bug, just simply the nature of the beast.  while training a bazillion selectors into a giant, single, pretty selector looks cool...it has always been a HUGE performance decrease.

Comment: I don't know exactly why but [this site](http://www.sitepoint.com/efficient-jquery-selectors/) provide some tips of how improve jQuery selector performance...

Comment: here's an interesting article https://gist.github.com/Raynos/1417030

Comment: First, ALWAYS give a tag name when selecting classes. Otherwise it has to look through every single element on the page to match the class name. You should also always try to start from an element with an ID, like: $('#some_element div.class_name')...

Comment: I've noticed similar speed degradation in IE as well. See - http://jsperf.com/id-vs-class-vs-tag-selectors/2 - for details

Comment: Complex selectors will always be slower because they have to run through the sizzle engine. Separating out the selector is the easiest way to speed things up.

Comment: @Derek *"First, ALWAYS give a tag name when selecting classes"* that's true for IE7/8, but with modern browsers that matters far less, and in some cases (firefox) it a good bit faster to use on the classname. None of this really matters though unless it's causing a performance problem. a classname + tagname makes very little difference, the problem here is the `:contains`

Comment: `:contains` is a performance black hole, a brother of `:has`.

Answer (score 0):

An important reason of multiple selectors separated with "," being slower than multiple selections is: all the jQuery collections you want to directly merge when using a large selector forces jQuery to sort them in the order they appear in the document.

And I think that in your case "padding before" and "padding after" elements are quite interleaved thus causing a long merge reordering time.

And about ":contains"... If you write the templates you are likely to prefer adding a class for those elements.

Generally performance means using selectors you know being optimized DOM side.